# What is the correct way to declare function's argumemt's type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
interface Note { ... }

interface Notebook {
    name: string,
    note: Note[]
}

interface NotebookApi {
    createNotebook(name: Notebook['name']): Notebook
    ...
}
```

Is it right way to declare type as `Notebook['name']` or I must use `string` instead of it?

Comment: Other than the ellipses and use of `Notes` instead of `Note`, that code is fine.  `Notebook['name']` and `string` are the same type, and either way is fine.   Is this just something you haven't tested?  Or are you aware that it works but want an opinion on what the "right" way to do it is?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I wanted to know about conventions about it. "Notes" is a typo, I'll edit it.

Comment: I would use `createNotebook(name: string): Notebook` but I don't know if that's "right" or just personal preference.  I find it more readable.